# Implements MouseListener vs addMouseListener

Tags: java, events, mouseevent, mouselistener

Hu guys,

I have a strange behavior implementing MouseListener interface vs addMouseListener.
This is my code:

```
public class SwitchButton extends JPanel {
    public static final Dimension PREF_SIZE = new Dimension(32, 16);
    private SwitchButtonModel switchButton;

    public SwitchButton() {
       this.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 0, (int)PREF_SIZE.getWidth(), (int)PREF_SIZE.getHeight()));
       switchButton = new SwitchButtonModel();
       addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
           @Override
           public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
               switchButton.toggleStatus();
           }
       });
    }
```

This code works. The toggleStatus() method of the switchButton is executed when I click in the area of my panel.

If I implement the interface MouseListener the event mouseClicked is never called.

```
public class SwitchButton extends JPanel implements MouseListener {
    public static final Dimension PREF_SIZE = new Dimension(32, 16);
    private SwitchButtonModel switchButton;

    public SwitchButton() {
        this.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 0, (int)PREF_SIZE.getWidth(), (int)PREF_SIZE.getHeight()));
        switchButton = new SwitchButtonModel();

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
            switchButton.toggleStatus();

        }
... All other methods of MouseListener interface ...
```

Why? Can you help me?
Thank you!

Comment: Because you never add the mouse listener in the second case. You still need to do `addMouseListener(this)`.

Comment: Oh my god which foolishness! Thank you very much!